# Variable point needs to be final

Tags: android, google-maps, maps

I am getting an error that says "Variable 'point' is accessed from inner class, needs to be declared final". The error is on the last "point" on.position

```
googleMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onMapLongClick(LatLng point) {
        googleMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onMapLongClick(LatLng point) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                builder.setTitle("Title");

                // Set up the input
                final EditText input = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
                builder.setView(input);

                // Set up the buttons
                builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {@Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        String text = input.getText().toString();
                        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(point)
                            .title(text));
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

declare point as `final`

```
@Override
public void onMapLongClick(final LatLng point) {
```

Comment: god I feel stupid, typed "LatLng final point" and I just couldn't understand lmao

Answer (score 0):

You need to do exactly what it says and make `point` `final`

```
public void onMapLongClick(LatLng p) {
    final LatLng point = p;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not changing the value of point you can declare it final. Then you can access it in your inner class.

Change:

```
@Override
public void onMapLongClick(LatLng point) {
```

to:

```
@Override
public void onMapLongClick(final LatLng point) {
```